# Difference in .class file with Intellij and javac

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am switching to `IntelliJ IDEA` and have seen some difference between the compiled class file generated by `IntelliJ` and `javac`. I am very sure that I am missing/overlooking some setting configuration in the `IntelliJ` which is causing this issue. Here is the sample java code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   List<String> s = new ArrayList<>();
   s.add("ksajhdjhdf");
   System.out.println(s.get(0));
}
```

Here are the compiled `.class` file

**IntellIJ**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> s = new ArrayList();
    s.add("ksajhdjhdf");
    System.out.println((String)s.get(0));
}
```

**javac command**

```
public static void main(String[] var0) {
    ArrayList var1 = new ArrayList();
    var1.add("ksajhdjhdf");
    System.out.println((String)var1.get(0));
}
```

javac output seems to be more correct (type information is erased), but can someone help me with following queries

1. Why the difference in `.class` file? Is it because I am missing some settings in IntelliJ?
2. I am not sure if the IntelliJ de-compiler is causing this difference.

Comment: IntelliJ knows where tge source file is so it uses that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In IntelliJ IDEA the setting `Generate debugging info` is probably enabled in `Preferences | Build, Execution, Deployment | Compiler | Java Compiler`. While developing it is a good idea to keep this enabled, to make debugging easier. But javac compiles without debugging info by default. To enabled debug info for javac use the `-g` flag.